# What's the right syntax for selecting a sum of values represented by previously selected values?

Tags: mysql

In pseudo code I'd like to accomplish this:

```
select 
count(groupA) as gA,
count(groupB) as gB,
count(groupC) as gC,
sum(gA,gB,gC) as groupABCTotal
```

But the various ways I've tried has resulted in syntax errors.  What's the correct way to achieve this without re-selecting the group counts for the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the sum as another column of output, you'll have to re-select the constituent columns in one fashion or another.

I find this rather readable:

```
SELECT d.*, gA+gB+gC AS groupABCTotal
FROM (SELECT COUNT(groupA) AS gA,
             COUNT(groupB) AS gB,
             COUNT(groupC) AS gC
        FROM tbl) d;
```

But this works, too, as you know:

```
SELECT COUNT(groupA) AS gA,
       COUNT(groupB) AS gB,
       COUNT(groupC) AS gC,
       COUNT(groupA)+COUNT(groupB)+COUNT(groupC) AS groupABCTotal
 FROM tbl;
```

Now, MySQL is probably smart enough not to recompute redundant aggregrates, so that COUNT(groupA) would be computed only once in the second form above.

Comment: unfortunately due to the nature of my query, I think it's easier for me to just total the results in the external code that runs this query. Thanks though.